# BeautifulSoup4 Parsing inside tag hierarchy

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble understanding how the bs4 parsing works to pull out information that is several levels down in a tag hierarchy.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to parse (from [www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=50](http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=50)):

```
...
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div onmouseover="toggle('clue_DJ_1_1', 'clue_DJ_1_1_stuck', '&lt;em class=&quot;correct_response&quot;&gt;&lt;i&gt;The Red Badge of Courage&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;table width=&quot;100%&quot;&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;right&quot;&gt;Kelley&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;')" onmouseout="toggle('clue_DJ_1_1', 'clue_DJ_1_1_stuck', 'This classic by Stephen Crane is subtitled &quot;An Episode of the American Civil War&quot;')" onclick="togglestick('clue_DJ_1_1_stuck')">
```

I specifically want to get out the words "The Red Badge of Courage", so that's within `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, and `<div>`, and then appears to be part of the attribute `onmouseover`.

I can pull out all `onmouseover` statements with:

```
for tag in soup.findAll(onmouseover=True):
    print(tag['onmouseover'])
```

But I don't know hot to parse inside that ouput.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the original html page? It's difficult to debug with just a snippet of the html.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just edited to add the link to www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=50.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the text you're interested in is in the `<em>` tags, it's pretty easy to parse using substring indexing:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get('http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=50')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')

for tag in soup.findAll('div',onmouseover=True):
    parseText = str(tag['onmouseover'])
    tag1 = '<em class="correct_response">'
    tag2 = '</em>'
    i1 = parseText.index(tag1)
    i2 = parseText.index(tag2)
    print(parseText[i1+len(tag1):i2])
```

This code got all of the entries until 'Final Jeopardy'.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! Obviously, I was missing the ability to get just the text out of the `<em>` tags. Thanks again.